# How do I add an [(ngModel)] and Datetime format to ionic V7 ion-datetime

Tags: ionic7

I am testing the ionic V7 ion-datetime I am able to bind the (ionChange) to an [(ngModel)] and format the change.  What I am trying to do is link the ion-datetime-button to an [(ngModel)] and format to YYYY-MM-DD.  is this possible.

html

```
    <ion-datetime-button datetime="TESTID"></ion-datetime-button>
    
    <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
      <ng-template>
        <ion-datetime
          #popoverDateMain
          [showDefaultButtons]="true"
          id="TESTID"
          presentation="date"
          displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" // Does nothing
          min="{{minDateAvailable}}"
          max="{{today}}"
          (ionChange)="item.Input = formatDate(popoverDateMain.value)" // links to [(ngModel)]
        >
      </ion-datetime>
```

ts

```
import { format, parseISO } from 'date-fns';

formatDate(value: any) { return format(parseISO(value), 'yyyy-MM-dd'); }

getToday() {
   this.today = this.formatDate(new Date().toISOString())
   return this.today;
}

minDate(){
  this.min = new Date();
  this.min.setMonth( this.min.getMonth()-6)
  this.min = this.min.toISOString();
  this.minDateAvailable = this.formatDate(this.min);
  return this.minDateAvailable;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something in what you're trying to achieve here, but it seems you're simply overthinking/overcomplicating it.

If you set `ngModel` directly to a string in the desired and [supported](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#iso-8601-datetime-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmz) format, it should just work.

Here's a bare-bones example that should get you going:

TS...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule, FormsModule]
})
export class DatepickerPage {
  #date: string = '2023-04-20T12:00';
  get date(): string { return this.#date };
  set date(val: string) {
    this.#date = val;
    console.log(this.date);
  };

  constructor() { }
}
```

HTML...

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Date Picker Test</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime"></ion-datetime-button>

  <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
    <ng-template>
      <ion-datetime
        id="datetime"
        [(ngModel)]="date"
      >
      </ion-datetime>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-modal>
</ion-content>
```

Here's some console output changing the date or time...

```
datepicker.page.ts:18 2023-04-06T12:00:00
datepicker.page.ts:18 2023-04-06T13:00:00
```

If I'm missing something please say and I can see about updating this.

Here's [a repo](https://github.com/pecknigel/ionic-angular-ts-experimentation/tree/6d6b5038a693cb22c2bf980162d7707763cf296e) with the code.

Comment: You are right I was way over thinking it and using the V6 format to much

Comment: The only real issue I seen is if you have multiple date times in the form

Comment: Multiple datetimes? What are you referring to?

Comment: Some forms can have multiple date entries.  Start date, end date, date due.  That’s why I had the ionChange so I could use the same code across multiple form entries. Item.input is multiple ngModels from an question array

Comment: In that case the usual approach is to make it a component and reuse the code that way.

Comment: can anyone help me to fix this issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566749/how-to-hide-dial-pad-or-key-board-in-ion-datetime-ionic-capacitor