# How to Hide Dial pad or key board in ion-datetime (ionic capacitor)

Tags: reactjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic7

I am using ionic7 (ionic capacitor) As per my client's requirement I would like to hide the dial-pad/keyboard when the user clicks on the time (preferWheel).

```
  <ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
    <ng-template>
      <ion-datetime 
        id="date"
        min="{{minDate}}"
        max="{{maxDate}}"
        [(ngModel)]="formData._start"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
        (ionChange)="onStartDateChange($event)"
        [showDefaultButtons]="true"
        (ionCancel)="onStartDateCancel($event)"
        (click)="hidekeyboard()"
        #date
        presentation="date">
      </ion-datetime>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-modal>
```

Comment: <ion-datetime-button datetime="time"  value="formData._start"  class="startdate" *ngIf="timeSelect" ></ion-datetime-button> on click of this button Iam opening modal popup